# how to select only external tranzactions(column values) in oracle?

Tags: oracle, join, where-clause

i have a first table with id_client,id_card (info table)
and second with id_debet,id_credit,value,vale_info (tranzaction table)

```
      first table                    second table
______________________             ________________________________________________________
|id_client | id_card |            |id_debet  |id_credit | value | value info              |
|50102411  | 5166    |            | 5166     | 5167     | 300$  | transfer to client card |
|50102411  | 5167    |            | 5167     | 4931239  | 100$  | UBER taxi NY            |
|50102412  | 5168    |            | 5168     | 5169     | 200$  | transfer to client card |
|50102412  | 5169    |            | 5169     | 3582934  | 120$  | rent hotel room         |
______________________             ________________________________________________________

id_debet -> spend from your card
id_Debet -> replenishment to your card 
and i want to select only external tranzaction not between card clients
for ex 
if 5166 send money to 5167 i skip this tranzaction 
if 5166 send to another card i select it etc
```

Comment: Something is wrong. Shouldn't all the `id_debit` and `id_credit` from the second table appear in the `id_card` column in the first table? In your sample data, there are some `id_credit` numbers that aren't in the first table. How should that be handled? Other than that, do you know how to write a simple `join`? That's the first step, and it's pretty much all you need to do, except that you must join the second table to the first table TWICE, to get the "client_debit" and "client_credit" so you can use in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` query to find all transactions in the second table that have an `id_debet` or `id_credit` which is not in the first table:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.id_card = t2.id_debet)
  OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM table1 t1
                 WHERE t1.id_card = t2.id_credit)
```

Output:

```
id_debet    id_credit   value   value info
5167        4931239     100$    UBER taxi NY
5169        3582934     120$    rent hotel room
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ca5a111ddeef9adcfaeb3cf820ed69a)

Comment: but if talbe have thousand of clients and more cards ?
not only two client

Comment: As long as transactions only have an `id_debet` and `id_credit` column it will work fine. The two `EXISTS` clauses just check that *one* of the `id` values in those columns doesn't exist in the first table

Comment: @MakhmutSyzdykbayev you can play with the demo and add more clients and cards and see it working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as follows:

```
SELECT T.id_debet, T.id_credit, T.value, T.value info FROM tranzaction T 
JOIN info I ON I.id_card IN (T.id_debet, T.id_credit)
GROUP BY T.id_debet, T.id_credit, T.value, T.value
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```